# Using PHP and Forms to Manipulate Data

Tags: php, forms, input, textbox, output

I am new to php and I am having a hard time finding a good tutorial on how to do what I want to do. I know I want to have the feature to be able to add three variables and put the result into a textbox on the same page. Here is the code  I have. I am getting an error when trying to display the result into a textbox. Any help appreciated.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Field of View Calculator</title>
    </head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Test_Calculator.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="1000" align="center" border="10">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="khaki" colspan="6"><h1>Field of View</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">Input</td>
        <td align="center"" colspan="1">Intermediate Variables</td>
        <td align="center" colspan="1">Output</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"  colspan="1">Number of Rings:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rings" size="40"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" /></td>
        <td align="right">Number of Rings:</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Wavelength:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="wave" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Emitter Space:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="emitter" size="40"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">Static Values:</td>
        <td align="center" colspan="6"><textarea name="content" cols="115" rows="15"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></td>
    </tr>

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$result = 1 * 764000;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value to `$result` **before** you try to echo it out.

Move the last 5 lines to the top of the file.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that php forms worked that way